# form_tag routing missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a custom method `buy` inside the order controller

I've declared a special route with the following: which is `sell_order_path`

```
resources :orders do
  post 'sell', on: :member
end
```

And here's my form tag

```
<%= form_tag(sell_order_path, :params => params.merge(:id => 5, :stock_symbol =>'test')  ) do %>
  <%= label_tag :stock_name, 'Buy Quantity' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :stock_name, params[:quantity] %> 
  <%= submit_tag "Buy", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

When I click on the submit button, it says

```
No route matches {:controller=>"orders", :action=>"sell"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Any idea why? I need to pass in a total of 3 parameter to my `orders#sell`

1. id
2. stock_symbol
3. quantity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= form_tag(sell_order_path(5)) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :stock_symbol, 'test' %>
  <%= label_tag :stock_name, 'Buy Quantity' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :stock_name, params[:quantity] %> 
  <%= submit_tag "Buy", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

The error occurs because you need to pass appropriate object id to your url helper if it routes to resource member action. Also, I moved `stock_symbol` to hidden field inside your form.

Comment: @SteveNg You should rather use rails `Logger` class or gem `pry` (use it by adding `binding.pry` wherever you want to stop script from execution and "redirect" it to your console) to debug rails application.
Would you mind accepting the answer if it was helpful?